commands not working in android studio terminal
enter image description here
Facing this error while installing new packages and also while running commands
Facing this error while installing new packages and also while running commands.
I tried upgrading Flutter and Dart but the issue is still not solved.
I'm a beginner in flutter and do not have much knowledge about it.
I want you to see the error in pictures and help me in sorting out the problem!
Here is the code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp(), );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner
                       : false, title
                       : 'Flutter Demo',
                       // theme: ThemeData(
                       //   primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
                       // ),
                       home
                       : MyHomePage(), );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  var nameController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Shared Preferences'),
    ),
    body: Container(
    child: Column(
    children: [
    TextField(
    controller: nameController,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
    label: Text('Name'),
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(21),
    ),
    ),
    ),
    SizedBox(
    height: 11,
    ),
    OutlinedButton(
    onPressed: ()  {
      var name = nameController.text.toString();
    child: Text('Save'),),
    ],
    ),
    ),
    );
    }
  }


I think this answer will help you

This is what it shows when I run the command: flutter pub add shared_preferences
PS E:\hp laptop data\data1\BS soft Eng\8th semester\Fyp 2\My assistant app files\testing_shared_preferences> flutter pub add shared_preferences
Error:
The current Dart SDK version is 3.5.0-227.0.dev.
Because testing_shared_preferences requires SDK version >=3.22.1 <4.0.0, version solving failed.

Add the command and its error message to the question, not in a comment. Comments are hard to read, and not searchable.
